# Showing undefined in the button tag

Tags: javascript, html

Some simple question, Why it's showing undefined? What's causing of this? But when I click it, the undefined **disappear**.

Now my problem is how to fix it? I don't even know what to do now so I just need a little help in this simple code

```js
    if(bt === "Dark Mode") {
      
      document.getElementById('btntextt').innerHTML = "Light Mode"
      window.localStorage.btntext = 'Light Mode'
    } else {
      window.localStorage.btntext = 'Dark Mode'
      document.getElementById('btntextt').innerHTML = "Dark Mode"
    } 


// Retrieve
 var btnn = document.getElementById('btntextt').innerHTML = window.localStorage.btntext
```

```html
<!-- HTML CODE -->
 <button class="btn" id="btntextt" name="button">Dark Mode</button>
```

Now I want to change the text and save it in local storage when changing a theme, but... showing undefined when launching the web.

Thx for the help (in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be `window.localStorage.btntext` could be `undefined` for the first time when you are opening in your browser
To fix that

```
var btnn = document.getElementById('btntextt').innerHTML = (window.localStorage.btntext || "Dark Mode");
```

Comment: That actually worked! Thx my dude for the help I just actually remembered the "||" that I can use it for! Thx again

Comment: @Johnsiras _"Why it's showing undefined?"_ - `null` is not `undefined` o.O

Answer (score 0):

Try linking the script at the end of the body (if you didn't)

Comment: If the execution time of the script would be the problem, then it wouldn't work at all. But... _"But when I click it, the undefined disappear"_

Comment: And imho that should be a comment and not an answer.